# Difference between session from request and session from PageContext

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, pagecontext

Is there a difference?

```
PageContext pageContext = (PageContext) getJspContext();
HttpSession session = pageContext.getSession();
```

=session through PageContext

```
PageContext pageContext = (PageContext) getJspContext();
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) pageContext.getRequest();
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
```

=session through request

Comment: The Session  provides a way to identification across more than one page request while PageContext is provisioned for the Request

Answer (score 0):

No, **there is no difference** between these two session objects. [PageContext](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext.html) provides methods to facilitate access to HTTP and Session related objects from a JSP page, including [a mechanism to manage session usage by the page](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext.html)